tensorflow.keras.Normalization in Google Colab Notebook
Apologies if this is a basic question. In the following python code I try to normalize a simple tensor using a Google Colab notebook.
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization

normalizer = Normalization(mean=5, variance=4)
x_normalized = tf.constant([[3,4,5,6,7],
                            [4,5,6,7,8]])
normalizer(x_normalized)

What am I doing wrong? I get the error:
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node \__wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1 values, but the requested shape has 5 \[Op:Reshape\]

Is there an issue with tensorflow.keras.Normalization in a Google colab notebook?

The issue arose because you provided scalar values for the mean and variance,
which assumed a single feature per sample.The error due to broadcasting, to
address this, i correctly adjusted the code by passing lists of values, where
each list contains the mean and variance for each of the five features per
sample.Please refer to this gist to see changes i made
